# Unable to select <TR>

Tags: html, css

I want to use css to change the property of the `<tr>` contents, like give it a red border. However doing the below code doesnt work on `<tr>`, but works on `<td>`. Did something go wrong?

**CSS:**

```
#leaderboard tr {
border: 1px red solid;
}

.leaderboard {
border: 1px red solid;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="leaderboard">
    <tr class="leaderboard"><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr class="leaderboard"><td>There!</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: border isn't generally respected on tr's in IE.

Comment: this must be an IE issue. the code you have works for me on firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/hkCxc/

Answer (score 1):

Imho you can't give the tr border properties because only the individual cells have borders (in IE).
So the most simple solution would be to give the table left and right border and the cells top and bottom ones.

```
#leaderboard {
    border: 1px red solid;
}

#leaderboard td {
    border-top: 1px red solid;
    border-bottom: 1px red solid;
}
```

Comment: alternative to giving the table itself the left and right you could also just have a class on the first and last cells and apply the appropriate border to them.

Answer (score 0):

[Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/2ePqp/) in Chrome and Firefox. Are you using a modern, standards-compliant browser?

Comment: This is pretty much summed up in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This works in IE8, FF5.

```
<style type="text/css">
.td{
    border:1px solid red;
    border-top:0;
    height:28px;
   }
</style>

<table width="300px" style="border-top:1px solid red;border-right:1px solid red;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="td" style="width:50px;">head1</td>                           
        <td class="td" style="width:50px;">head2</td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td class="td">cell1</td>                              
        <td class="td">cell2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

To my understanding, TR doesn't take up layout space the way other elements might.  You'd be well advised to trade your tables/tr/td structure with nested, classed DIVs, like so:

```
<div id='leaderboard'>
    <div class='leaderboard'>Hello</div>
    <div class='leaderboard'>There</div>
</div>
```

There's nothing that you can do with tables that you can't do with `div`s, but conversely there's a lot `div`s CAN do that `table`s can't.

Comment: Leaderboards *are* tables after all.

Comment: @boltclock, yes - but they don't table particularly *well* is the trouble.

Comment: -1 I'm not sure i understand what it means to "table well", but there are certain things tables are best suited for, such as a leaderboard containing names, scores and dates for instance.